# How to add a duplicate to right-click menu in Files via contractor entry

Tags: release-hera, pantheon-files

I'm trying to create a contractor that duplicate a file.

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Duplicate File
Icon=File
Description=Duplicate file...
MimeType=application/octet-stream;application/binary
Exec=cp %f %f_copy
Gettext-Domain=file
```

But no way to work.

Comment: You can find information on how to use shell commands with contractor here: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/14075/image-resize-contract.

Comment: You can duplicate files easily by selecting, then press `<Ctrl>C` then `<Ctrl>V`.

Comment: I know how to use the shortcuts. What I want is to create a contractor for that.